# Annual report of the Town of Plymouth, MA [1925]

Tags: vital-records, 1920s, massachusetts

I'm looking for the Annual report of the Town of Plymouth, MA for the year 1925.

According to the following blog post from the Plymouth Public Library, Annual reports are available on the Internet Archive
https://www.plymouthpubliclibrary.org/blog/2015/02/12/annual-reports-now-online/

...but in the Internet Archive there are several missing years. Not only 1925, the one that matters to me, but also, for example, 1923, 1927 and 1929.
https://archive.org/search.php?query=municipal%20reports%20plymouth%20ma&sort=-date

Was this report a plurianual edition? If not, why there are missing years, and where can I find the report for 1925?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may know, what you are looking at are the Town Reports for the town of Plymouth. Almost every town in New England publishes a town report every spring for Town Meeting(usually March). Many towns have done so for nearly 400 years. The older town reports tend to include all sorts of useful information, like every birth, death, and marriage (along with the date and name of those involved) that occurred during the prior calendar year, property transfers, names of town officers, who was delinquent in their taxes and by how much, who was living at the Poor Farm, etc.. The Town Reports also almost always include the school report, which can tell you things like how many kids were enrolled at each school. For privacy reasons, the newer reports don't tend to include names of people, but you can still find a lot of interesting demographic data in them.

Anyway, regarding your specific question, it appears that between about 1920 and 1936, the town of Plymouth published their town reports in multi-year volumes. In this case, 1924 and 1925 are published together. So the 1925 report (which covers all the events that occurred in 1924) can be found starting on page 335 of the 1924-1925 book: https://archive.org/details/annualreportoft1924unse_0/page/n335

As an aside, there is a very interesting graph between pages 246 and 247 of the 1925 report showing the total amount of water stored in the town reservoirs throughout the year.

If you had been unable to find the report online, my first suggestion in all cases would have been to contact the Town Clerk for that town, as they often keep the old reports on hand. If they don't, they would certainly be able to put you in contact with the town historical society or library, either of which might keep the old reports.